# Getting Parameters in Lightning Web Components

Tags: lightning-web-components

This seems like a super simple question but I can't find the answer for the life of me.  I have an app that is going to edit records in a new Lightning App Page with a Lightning Web Component in it.

When I go to this App Page, the Id is being passed as a URL parameter.

How do I get the value of a query string parameter in the js file of a Lightning Web Component?

Comment: please update your post with the code you have tried and where you are stuck exactly =)  thanks

Comment: I don't have much code yet, I'm just starting and trying to figure out how to get the value of a query string parameter.

Comment: get the value of a query string parameter in what context? lighting communities, LEX ?

Comment: Not to sound rude but a simple google search on 'get record id in LWC' would have answered your question. Something like this https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_record_context

Comment: You are correct, and I did find that, but that I think that only applies to record pages not app pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to specify [recordId as an @api member](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.use_record_context), and the framework will give you the ID automatically.

```
// testClass.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
export default class TestClass extends LightningElement {
    @api recordId;
}
```

---

You should also be able to access window.location.search to identify parameters.

Comment: Thank you.  I think @api recordId only works for Record pages, but you reminded me that I had been way overthinking the solution and I could use basic JS functionality to get what I needed.

Comment: Could you please answer a doubt I have here? If there are two params which I pass through the url, how can I access them in lwc.

Comment: @JayakrishnanSalim window.location.search or [CurrentPageReference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation).

Comment: @sfdcfox I placed an LWC on a VF page using Lightning out. I tried using CurrentPageReference but it didn't work in lightning out. Is window.location.search the only option to get URL params for lightning out?

Comment: @Koustubh Correct. CurrentPageReferece won't work outside Lightning Experience.

Answer (score 3):

In your case the best approach will be use

```
@api recordId;
```

In other cases, where you have also other parameters the best approach is to use **CurrentPageRefference**.

currentPageReference.state allows you to get params.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class Test extends LightningElement {

   currentPageReference = null; 
   urlStateParameters = null;

   urlId = null;
   urlLanguage = null;
   urlType = null;

   @wire(CurrentPageReference)
   getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
      if (currentPageReference) {
         this.urlStateParameters = currentPageReference.state;
         this.setParametersBasedOnUrl();
      }
   }

   setParametersBasedOnUrl() {
      this.urlId = this.urlStateParameters.id || null;
      this.urlLanguage = this.urlStateParameters.lang || null;
      this.urlType = this.urlStateParameters.type || '10';
   }
}
```

More details you can find here https://beyondthecloud.dev/blog/get-url-parameters-in-lwc

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameter by using both @api and visualforce

1) create lightning out application and state lwc 
// wrapTestClass.application //

```
<aura:application extends="ltng:outApp" >
    <aura:dependency resource="c:testClass" />
</aura:application>
```

2) create visualforce and pass parameters which defined as @api in lwc

```
<apex:page>
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <div id="test"></div>

    <script>
        $Lightning.use("c:wrapTestClass", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:testClass", {"recordId":"{!param}"}, "test", function(cmp, err) {}); 
        });
    </script>
</apex:page>
```