# Retrieving custom metadata values in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, custom-metadata

I have Custom Metadata Type values that I want to display in a Lighning Web Component. I've read a few different posts ([post 1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310549/how-get-custom-settings-or-custom-metadata-types-in-lwc-component-using-getrecor), [post 2](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/306986/lwc-record-detail-page-for-custom-metadata-type)) about this but neither seems to work for my scenario.

My Custom Metadata Type (API name: Billing_Custom_MetaData__mdt) has a field (customerUrl) that I need to display in my component:

**myLwcComponent.html**

```
<template>
  <div class="slds-m-around_medium>
    <p>Web address: {customerUrlValue}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

**myLwcComponent.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
const FIELDS = [
  'Billing_Custom_MetaData__mdt.customerUrl__c',
];

export default class LifeCycle extends LightningElement {
  @api recordId;
  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
  metaDataRecord;

  get customerUrlValue() {
    return this.metaDataRecord.data.fields.customerUrl.value;
  }
}
```

I'm new to LWC so I'm trying to follow those posts and Salesforce documentation ([Get Record Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/data_wire_example)) for correct information. However, the customerUrl value from Billing_Custom_MetaData__mdt isn't rendering in my component.

Comment: Should the field be `customerUrl__c` or is that just a copy/paste typo?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves good question. I can try that, past reading didn't indicate to include `__c` are part of the name. Looks like that didn't work either.

Comment: I would update your code in the post to `customerUrl__c` so it's clear for the next person that reads this. Something that would be helpful for you is to include a `debugger` statement inside of `customerUrlValue()` to see what `metaDataRecord.data` is when the method is called to verify that the record is being loaded correctly and then narrow down that the field value is being retrieved. Likely permissions will be a factor.

Answer (score 3):

in wire method metaDataRecord   you are passing recordid.
please note that recordid  you defined  is calculated  based on scope of page and it is not metadatatype record id.
if it is a record detail page,it provides you recordid of that record.

you cannot use this recordid  to fetch metadatatype records.

best option is querying metadata records using apex and call apex in lwc.
(as per my **limited** knowledge of salesforce,this is best option)

if you want to avoid apex,  you have to hardcode  your metadatatype id in wire call  if it works  for you  but definitely not recommended.

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: 'hardcodedi id of metadata record', fields: FIELDS })
  metaDataRecord;
```

Comment: and customerUrl   should be replaced with api name of field  in import and getter method  as you discussed in comments